# Arabic fonts for Android

Tags: android, fonts, arabic

I am new in android world. I have issue with arabic font on android device they overlap each other . And some of them are unreadable please help where i am wrong or provide some solution for it.

Comment: any reason for down vote

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: then what should i ask for? I have issue wiith arabic font in android . its overlap on android phone but works good in word etc etc . I am developing an app which uses arabic language

Comment: I didn't downvote :) I just explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used **Cavorting.otf** downloaded from google and worked fine for me. I also increased font size to 25sp so it can be readable easily. I recommend you to increase the font size then try changing different fonts.